# Some questions about Cuntz’s proof of the $ K_{1} $-injectivity of purely infinite simple unital $ C^{*} $-algebras

Tags: proof-verification, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I have some questions about Joachim Cuntz’s proof of the $ K_{1} $-injectivity of purely infinite simple unital $ C^{*} $-algebras, which is found in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971137?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

For this post, let us adopt the following definitions and terminology for a $ C^{*} $-algebra $ A $.

- If $ A $ is unital, then $ \mathcal{U}(A) $ denotes the set of unitaries of $ A $. Observe that $ \mathcal{U}(A) $ is a group.
- If $ A $ is unital, then $ {\mathcal{U}_{0}}(A) $ denotes the set of unitaries of $ A $ that are connected to $ 1_{A} $ by a path in $ \mathcal{U}(A) $. Observe that $ {\mathcal{U}_{0}}(A) $ is a subgroup of $ \mathcal{U}(A) $.
- If $ A $ is unital, then $ \sim $ is an equivalence relation on $ \mathcal{U}(A) $, where $ u \sim v \stackrel{\text{df}}{\iff} u v^{-1} \in {\mathcal{U}_{0}}(A) $.
- $ \sim_{\text{M-vN}} $ is the Murray-von Neumann equivalence relation between projections of $ A $.
- A projection $ p \in A $ is called **infinite** if and only if there exists another projection $ p' \in A $ such that $ p \sim_{\text{M-vN}} p' \lneq p $.
- $ A $ is called **purely infinite** if and only if $ \overline{x A x} $ contains an infinite projection for every positive element $ x \in A $.

---

Let me first state two important lemmas found in the paper.

> **Lemma 1.** Let $ A $ be a simple $ C^{*} $-algebra. Then the set $ S $ of infinite projections of $ A $ satisfies:
>   $$
> (\star) \quad
> \text{For all $ p,q \in S $, there exists a $ p' \in S $ such that $ p \sim_{\text{M-vN}} p' \lneq q $ and $ q - p' \in S $}.
> $$
>   If $ A $ is furthermore purely infinite, then every non-zero projection of $ A $ is infinite.
>
> **Lemma 2.** Let $ A $ be a purely infinite (not-necessarily-simple) unital $ C^{*} $-algebra. Then for every $ u \in \mathcal{U}(A) $, there exist a projection $ p \in A $ with $ 0_{A} \lneq p \lneq 1_{A} $ and a $ u' \in \mathcal{U}(p A p) $ such that
>   $$
> u \sim u' + (1_{A} - p).
> $$
>   **Note:** The corner $ p A p $ is a unital $ C^{*} $-subalgebra of $ A $ with $ p $ as its identity.

I was able to verify the proofs of these lemmas (after much difficulty), but I was unable to do so for the next one.

> **Lemma 3.** Let $ A $ be a purely infinite **simple** unital $ C^{*} $-algebra. Let $ u \in \mathcal{U}(A) $ and $ e $ a minimal projection of $ \mathscr{K} $, the compact operators on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. Then $ u \in {\mathcal{U}_{0}}(A) $ if and only if
>   $$
> e \otimes u + (\mathbf{1} - e \otimes 1_{A}) \sim \mathbf{1}
> $$
>   in $ (\mathscr{K} \otimes A)^{+} $, where $ (\mathscr{K} \otimes A)^{+} $ is the unitization of $ \mathscr{K} \otimes A $ and $ \mathbf{1} $ denotes its identity.

*Reproduction of Cuntz’s proof*

Of course, we only have to show the ‘if’ part. By Lemma $ 2 $, we may assume that
$$
u = p u p + (1_{A} - p) \qquad (\clubsuit)
$$
for a proper projection $ p \in A $. By $ (\star) $, there is, then, a projection $ q \in A $ such that

- $ 0_{A} \lneq q \lneq 1_{A} - p $ and
- $ q \sim_{\text{M-vN}} 1_{A} - p $.

Again by $ (\star) $, we can find a sequence $ (r_{i})_{i \in \Bbb{N}} $ of mutually orthogonal projections of $ A $ such that
$$
\forall i \in \Bbb{N}: \quad
r_{i} \leq 1_{A} - p - q \quad \text{and} \quad
r_{i} \sim_{\text{M-vN}} 1_{A}.
$$
Set

- $ r_{0} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} p + q $ (note that $ r_{0} \sim_{\text{M-vN}} 1_{A} $) and
- $ f_{k} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} r_{0} + \cdots + r_{k} $ for all $ k \in \Bbb{N} $.

Then $ f_{k} A f_{k} \cong {\text{M}_{k}}(\Bbb{C}) \otimes A $, and the $ C^{*} $-algebra generated by $ \displaystyle \bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{N}} f_{k} A f_{k} $ and $ 1_{A} $ is isomorphic to $ (\mathscr{K} \otimes A)^{+} $. This isomorphism carries $ e \otimes u + (\mathbf{1} - e \otimes 1_{A}) $ to $ u $. $ \quad \blacksquare $

---

> **Questions.** Why may we assume $ (\clubsuit) $ by Lemma $ 2 $, and more importantly, how do we establish that $ f_{k} A f_{k} $ is isomorphic to $ {\text{M}_{k}}(\Bbb{C}) \otimes A $?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: From Lemma 2 you have that $pup\sim pu'p=u'$

Comment: @Phoenix87: Hi Phoenix87. Thanks for your comment! You’re right. From Lemma $ 2 $, we have
$$
u \sim v \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} u' + (1_{A} - p) \in \mathcal{U}(A)
$$
for some proper projection $ p $ of $ A $ and some $ u' \in \mathcal{U}(p A p) $. Observe that
\begin{align}
p v p
& = p u' p + p (1_{A} - p) p \\
& = p u' p + 0_{A} \\
& = u'. \quad (\text{As $ p $ is the identity element of $ p A p $.})
\end{align}
Hence, $ v = p v p + (1_{A} - p) $, and as $ u \sim v $, we’re done, for then $ [u]_{1} = [v]_{1} $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will write $f_k=r_1+\cdots+r_k$, because otherwise we get $M_{k+1}(\mathbb C)$.

The projections $r_j$ are each equivalent to $1_A$, so there exist partial isometries $e_{1,j},\ldots,e_{1,k}$ with 
$$
e_{1,j}^*e_{1,j}^\vphantom{*}=r_j,\ \ \ \ e_{1,j}^\vphantom{*}e_{1,j}^*=r_1.
$$
Now define
$$
e_{k,j}^\vphantom{*}=e_{1,k}^*e_{1,j}^\vphantom{*}.
$$
This is a system of matrix units in $A$, i.e. 
$$\tag{1}
e_{k,j}^\vphantom{*}e_{s,t}^\vphantom{*}=\delta_{j,s}^\vphantom{*}\,e_{k,t}^\vphantom{*}.
$$
Now define $\varphi:f_kAf_k\to M_k(\mathbb C)\otimes r_1Ar_1$ by 
$$
\varphi(x)=\sum_{k,j=1}^k E_{k,j}\otimes e_{1,k}\,x\,e_{j,1}.
$$
This maps is obviously linear, it is multiplicative and preserves adjoints by using the properties $(1)$. It is one-to-one, because if $e_{1,k}\,x\,e_{j,1}=0$ for all $k,j$, we get $r_kxr_j=0$, and by adding over all $k,j$ we get $0=f_kxf_k=x$. It is onto, because for $y_{k,j}^\vphantom{*}\in r_1Ar_1$, 
$$
\sum_{k,j=0}^kE_{k,j}\otimes y_{k,j}^\vphantom{*}=\varphi(\sum_{k,j}e_{k,1}^\vphantom{*}y_{k,j}^\vphantom{*}e_{1,j}^\vphantom{*}).
$$
So it remains to show that $A\simeq r_1Ar_1$. This follows from the fact that $r_1\sim 1_A$. Indeed, there exists a partial isometry $w$ with $w^*w=1_A$, and $ww^*=r_1$. Now define $\psi:r_1Ar_1\to A$ by
$$
\psi(x)=w^*xw.
$$
A straighforward check shows that $\psi$ is a $*$-homomorphism. If $\psi(x)=0$, then $w^*xw=0$; then $0=ww^*xww^*=r_1xr_1=x$. And given any $y\in A$, we have $wyw^*\in r_1Ar_1$ (because $w=r_1w$), and so $\psi(wyw^*)=y$. So $\psi$ is bijective.

Comment: Thank you once again, Martin. I actually figured it out myself already but just didn’t have the time to post an answer. It appears that Cuntz committed a typo error when he claimed that $ f_{k} A f_{k} \cong {\text{M}_{k}}(\Bbb{C}) \otimes A $ for each $ k \in \Bbb{N} $. Instead, it should be $ f_{k} A f_{k} \cong {\text{M}_{k + 1}}(\Bbb{C}) \otimes A $ for each $ k \in \Bbb{N}_{0} $.

Comment: You are welcome. The typo is not surprising, this is very standard stuff so he likely didn't spend time thinking about this when he wrote the paper.